# Why does selecting from _Sent and LEFT JOIN _Job return null values from _Job

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views, sqlserver

When I select from _Sent and LEFT JOIN _Job it returns null values for fields selected from _Job.

I'm querying from the Parent BU so this shouldn't be the BU specific issue.

```sql
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey,
j.EmailName,
j.EmailSubject,
jy.JourneyName,
jy.VersionNumber,
s.EventDate AS event_date,
'Sent' as event_type
FROM _Sent s
LEFT JOIN _Job j ON s.JobID = j.JobID
LEFT JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN _Journey jy ON ja.VersionID = jy.VersionID
WHERE
s.EventDate > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate()) and jy.JourneyID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

But when I flip the select from _Sent to _Job, and LEFT JOIN _Sent, it doesn't return null values.

```sql
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey,
j.EmailName,
j.EmailSubject,
jy.JourneyName,
jy.VersionNumber,
s.EventDate AS event_date,
'Sent' as event_type
FROM _Job j
LEFT JOIN _Sent s ON s.JobID = j.JobID
LEFT JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN _Journey jy ON ja.VersionID = jy.VersionID
WHERE
s.EventDate > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate()) and jy.JourneyID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should I always be selecting from _Job first then joining the other engagement data views. E.g Click, Open etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm querying from the Parent BU so this shouldn't be the BU specific issue."

It very likely is.

While most other data views tell you the BU context in `OYBAccountId` and can be queried from Parent BU, _Job data view does not.

The _Job data view contains only jobs from the BU you are running the query in.

So: Querying _Job in Parent returns only jobs that were performed in parent.

In contrast: Querying _Sent from Parent returns all sends and uses `OYBAccountId`  to tell you where they occurred.

So in order to get jobs from a child BU, you could retrieve the data in the child BU(s) _jobs Data View(s) with an SQL in each Child BU, store the data in one shared DE each, and pick it up in a followup query in Parent. That query can JOIN the shared DE with your other data already gathered in Parent.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. To clarify - the journey data I'm querying is in the Parent BU, so I dont need any data from Child BUs hence why I was confident it's not the BU specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

JobIDs for any Triggered Sends and Journey Builder emails don't get updated until a publish event occurs. The _Job data will drop-off after 6 months if a trigger or Journey Builder email doesn't get published.

For that reason, when selecting by date you should always should start with `_Sent` data and then join to `_Job`.

Or, what I like to do is maintain a canonical record of jobs using the [Send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/send.html) and [TriggeredSendSummary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/triggeredsendsummary.html) SOAP object data.

I've outlined that process on here on my blog:

- [Retrieving and Storing Aggregated Send Data](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/)
- [Retrieving and Storing Aggregated Triggered Send Data](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-triggered-send-data/)

If you've got a historical record of job data (JobID = ID) that also illustrates the publish events, you can start at `Send` or `TriggeredSendSummary` and join to `_Sent`.

An additional benefit of maintaining this data: you get a slew of aggregated activity data that you can use for many other reporting needs.

Comment: Thanks Adam. 
"For that reason, when selecting by date you should always should start with _Sent data and then join to _Job." 
Does this also apply to other Email data views such as Click, Open etc?

Comment: It depends on what date is most important -- the "send" date or the date the activity occurred.  If the send date is most important, then start with a source that doesn't drop data after 6 months.